# Why does orientation preserving maps respect CR?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, cauchy-riemann-equations

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687487/conformal-map-iff-holomorphic) it is written that "orientation preserving conformal maps respect CR. The matrix of the map must be a constant multiplied by some matrix of rotation that has a positive determinant. When this matrix is seen as the Jacobian of some function, you shall be able to show that the function respects CR."

I am not sure how to show this. Any help would be great. I think it has to do something with approaching a point parallel to one of the axis...

Comment: Which part are you unsure about? There is a lot of stuff there.